# Working bin/bas returns error when executed from run script Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a working shell script that works with no problems but when I executed it with a run script i get the following error:

[image]

The script will scan all the proto files in a directory and convert it to Swift using ProtoBuf. After that I will move the swift files into an App folder. The script code is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

for protoFile in ./*.proto;
    do
        protoc --swift_out=. $protoFile
done

for file in ./*.swift;
    do
        mv $file ../Convert\ AV/Model/USBDongle/Proto/
done
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the script from the directory it was located. When Xcode executes the the script that assumption is false. So I am getting the directory where the script is located and I do the logic with that path

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get Directory where the script is located
baseDirectory=$(dirname "$0")
echo "$baseDirectory"

for protoFile in "$baseDirectory"/*.proto
    do
        echo $protoFile
        protoc --swift_out="$baseDirectory" -I "$baseDirectory" "$protoFile"
done

for protoFileSwift in "$baseDirectory"/*.swift;
    do
        echo $protoFile
        mv "$protoFileSwift" "$baseDirectory"/../Convert\ AV/Model/USBDongle/Proto
done
```

*** /* Makes like is a comment... ***